# i am trying to make a voice assistant to control my room and the response times are very slow

Tags: python-3.x

I got a basic code on the internet and edited it to fit my requirements, on the hardware side I used Arduino uno, relays, and esp8266 esp01 wifi module, and controlled it using blynk and ifttt

the problem is that the assistant is very slow, I first thought that maybe google text to speech is the problem so I tried the pyttsx3 module to do that offline but that didn't help.
so I thought maybe the if statements are a problem so I made each one of them into a function and tried multi-threading but that didn't help either...

so I thought that it has to listen and process all I speak .. so I added a trigger word so only after the trigger word is used it starts to listen for commands,

sometimes it will work properly at first then get slower
I don't know what else to do

here is the code I am using:

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr 
import datetime
import wikipedia 
import webbrowser
import os
import requests
import time
import smtplib
from goto import goto, label



engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wishMe():
    
     

    speak("Hello sir ,Assistant booting up")       

def takeCommand():
    

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 0.5
        audio = r.listen(source)
        print("saving")

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")    
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)    
        print("Say that again please...")  
        return 
    return query


   


i=0
j=0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    wishMe()
    while True:
        print("iteration jarvis",i)
        i=i+1
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("waiting...")
            r.pause_threshold = 0.5
            audio = r.listen(source)
        try:    
            query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
            print(f"User said: {query}\n")
            if 'Jarvis' in query:
                query=takeCommand().lower()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)    
            print("jaris not called")
            continue 
        print("iteration command",j)
        j=j+1
        if 'how are you' in query:
            speak("good")
        elif 'open google' in query:
            webbrowser.open("google.com")
            speak("There you go!")
        elif 'lights on' in query:
            requests.post("https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/light_on/with/key/d*************") 
            speak("ok sure")  
        elif 'lights off' in query:
            requests.post("https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/lights_off/with/key/d************")  
            speak("with pleasure") 
        elif 'play music' in query:
            music_dir = 'D:\\Non Critical\\songs\\Favorite Songs2'
            songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
            print(songs)    
            os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0]))
        elif 'stop listening' in query:
            speak("going offline")
            exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to only initialize your recognizer once.

I took the liberty of cleaning up and refactoring the code a little too.

```
from itertools import count

import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser
import os
import requests

engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[0].id)

recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
recognizer.pause_threshold = 0.5


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def takeCommand():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)
        print("saving")
    print("Recognizing...")
    query = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="en-in")
    print(f"User said: {query}\n")
    return query


def process_query(query):
    if "how are you" in query:
        speak("good")
    elif "open google" in query:
        webbrowser.open("google.com")
        speak("There you go!")
    elif "lights on" in query:
        requests.post("https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/light_on/with/key/d*************")
        speak("ok sure")
    elif "lights off" in query:
        requests.post("https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/lights_off/with/key/d************")
        speak("with pleasure")
    elif "play music" in query:
        music_dir = "D:\\Non Critical\\songs\\Favorite Songs2"
        songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
        print(songs)
        os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0]))
    elif "stop listening" in query:
        speak("going offline")
        exit()


def main():
    speak("Hello sir ,Assistant booting up")
    for iteration in count(1):
        print("iteration jarvis", iteration)
        try:
            query = takeCommand()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            speak("Recognition error: {}".format(e))
        else:
            try:
                process_query(query)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                speak("Processing error: {}".format(e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Ok this works better now, but i actually want it to respond and start listening when i call it.